# AWS : Erro instalar php Myadmin

Tags: amazon-aws, phpmyadmin

Pessoal estou instalando o phpmyadmin instalei tudo ok, porem deu problema ao acessar o ip/phpmyadmin da o erro :

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

O meu php é o 7.0.16
Como posso arrumar ?
Obrigado

Comment: Linux ou Windows?

Comment: Linux da aws propia

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar os seguintes comandos:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

E depois:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Espero que funcione

Comment: nio caso a siat usa o yum, mudo o apt-get para yum?

Comment: ao rodaro primeiro comando deu : Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
1004 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package libapache2-mod-php7.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do